# Project layer reference to a foundation model

Tags: helix, solution-architecture

Our Sitecore solution has been designed following Sitecore's Helix principles and guidelines.

The project layer contains a few simple views that make up columns and sections on a page, very much like the Habitat solution.

We have a module in the foundation layer with some helper classes that retrieve render properties and parameters. We would like to use one of the methods from these classes in a view located in the project layer.

Would it be against the Helix layering principles if a project in the project layer calls directly a module in the foundation layer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes you can call module from foundation layer.

Please have a look here: https://helix.sitecore.net/principles/architecture-principles/layers.html for more details .

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Anything in the project layer CAN call anything in the foundation & feature layers. And since you could potentially make a feature that would also want to use the rendering parameters functionality, your design is perfect.